# INNER JOIN same table category and subcategory

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I need to make a inner join in a mysql table, but it's the same table.

I have a table categories:
An example of this table is:

```
id | id_lingua | id_registro | categoria | nivel
1    1           1             Pastas      0
2    2           1             Folders     0
3    3           1             Carpetas    0
4    1           2             Feminina    1
5    2           2             Women       1
6    3           2             Mujeres     1
```

nivel is the key that defines whether it is a category or sub category and I need to list these categories and next to specify the parent category level across the field that will contain the id_registro the parent category.

I do not know if I was clear but how do the inner join this table?

the table is:

```
id  id_lingua  id_registro  categoria  nivel
1   1          3            Pastas     0
2   2          3            Folders    0
3   3          3            Carpetas   0
4   1          4            Feminina   3
5   2          4            Women      3
6   3          4            Mujeres    3
```

and this consult:

```
SELECT cat.*, parent.categoria as nome
FROM categorias cat
INNER JOIN categorias parent
ON cat.nivel=parent.id_registro
AND cat.id_lingua=2
```

Return:

```
id  id_lingua  id_registro  categoria  nivel  nome
5   2          4            Women      3      Pastas
5   2          4            Women      3      Folders
5   2          4            Women      3      Carpetas
```

Comment: Can you show the data you want please?

Comment: Please show us what data your query gives you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want `LEFT JOIN` (which shows rows for which `parent` didn't get a match).

It also seems that you want to match on `id_lingua` as well.

```
SELECT cat.*, parent.categoria as nome
FROM categorias cat
LEFT JOIN categorias parent
ON cat.nivel = parent.id_registro
  AND cat.id_lingua = parent.id_lingua
WHERE cat.id_lingua = 2
```

You may also want to add [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull), since `parent.*` will be `NULL` for no match and it looks like you want `Empty` to be displayed: (unless you meant an actual empty string)

```
SELECT cat.*, IFNULL(parent.categoria, 'Empty') as nome
FROM categorias cat
LEFT JOIN categorias parent
ON cat.nivel = parent.id_registro
  AND cat.id_lingua = parent.id_lingua
WHERE cat.id_lingua = 2
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/1711796) has a nice picture explaining the difference between different joins:

[image]

Comment: Ok, so right back here with his explanation:
Not only returns the categories with level = 0

`SELECT cat. * , IFNULL( parent.categoria, 'Empty' ) AS nome FROM categorias cat
LEFT JOIN categorias parent ON cat.nivel = parent.id_registro
WHERE cat.id_lingua = parent.id_lingua
AND cat.id_lingua = '2'`

Comment: @EdersondosSantos `cat.id_lingua = parent.id_lingua` needs to be in the `JOIN` (like in my answer), because for level = 0, `parent.id_lingua` is `NULL`, so the check in `WHERE` will be false and it will not display those rows.

Comment: Google translated wrong what I said before. Sorry.

I meant that worked with his explanation, but does not return records with level = 0

Comment: but if I put it like this::`SELECT cat. * , IFNULL( parent.categoria, 'Empty' ) AS nome
FROM categorias cat
LEFT JOIN categorias parent ON cat.nivel = parent.id_registro
AND cat.id_lingua = parent.id_lingua
AND cat.id_lingua = '2'`

return all linguage

Comment: @EdersondosSantos `cat.id_lingua = '2'` still needs to be in the `WHERE`.

Comment: wonderful work now.

Thank you for your attention.`SELECT cat. * , IFNULL( parent.categoria, 'Empty' ) AS nome
FROM categorias cat
LEFT JOIN categorias parent ON cat.nivel = parent.id_registro
AND cat.id_lingua = parent.id_lingua
WHERE cat.id_lingua = '2'`